# How to capture each frame of a USB webcam using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, webcam

While I have got some leads from an [older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001828/vb-net-webcam) SO post and from [this](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_video_capture.html) site, I haven't been able to figure out how to capture each frame of a web-cam.

What I would like to do is something like this capture a frame then do some image processing on it and display the output and then move on to the next frame.
Can I can access to web-cam frame events or is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the perfect job for [OpenCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/projects/iplab/) image processing.

Comment: Have you worked on any of these which one would you recommend to start of with consider that I'm a noob in .net and image processing...

Comment: While I would have a look at the above links is there any specific solution using avicap32.dll I mean read each webcam frame, I mean get some events for each frame of the webcam. Is that possible?

Comment: I haven't used AForge, but I found emgu port of OpenCV very easy to use. I'm sure it's easy to look at frames with the MS apis, but they don't have much image processing built-in. The libraries I've suggested have lots of image processing and camera capture.

Answer (score 0):

This article will help you a lot:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/prototypingdsfilters.aspx

It shows how you can create your own DirectShow video filters in .NET

Comment: Haven't done much of C# so can't figure out what's going on out there, any thing in vb.net would be of great help...

Comment: There are web sites that will convert C# into VB.NET. Also there is almost a 1-1 matching of small syntax for > 90% of it.